# Coming "Ngrok command not found"

Tags: localhost, ngrok, tunnel

I tried to change my ngrok account. Now my local setup is not working. It show error like "**ngrok command not found**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngrok command is not found it is not installed in your windows

first try installing the ngrok in your system

> which ngrok

command in your command prompt or git bash terminal.

It shows the path of the ngrok try to add it in your environment variables, if it is not shown then move the executable file (ngrok.exe) to usr/local/bin path then restart your system.

command will work after that authentincate ngrok with your token

Comment: This works for me. You might not need to restart your system though.